# Android Studio else is always activating

Tags: android

I have this program that gets a character from a bluetooth device. When it gets a certain string it will either input a character, delete a character or speak a word from a string. But it is always trying to input a character or bypass the if else if statement regardless the condition is. here a sample code.

```
@Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            String readMessage;
            String RBCont;
            String btText;
            if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ){

                try {
                    readMessage = new String((byte[]) msg.obj, "UTF-8");
                    btText = readMessage;

                    btText = btText.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT);

                    if(btText.equals("BS")) {

                        RBCont = mReadBuffer.getText().toString();
                        RBCont = RBCont.substring(0, RBCont.length() - 1);
                        mReadBuffer.setText(RBCont);
                    }else if(btText.equals("SPK")){
                        speak();
                    }else{
                        mReadBuffer.append(btText);

                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


           }
```

Comment: "top input a character"? What do you mean?

Comment: im sorry it was to input a character on a certain variable/textview

Comment: Build your own test msg, pass it in and step through it.

Comment: @BradleyThomas the message is passing through correctly but it is bypassing the if elseif and just doing the else even though it has the correct string for example "BS", this will just display BS instead of deleting the character inside the textview

Comment: Have you examined the value of btText at the point execution gets to if(btText.equals("BS"))?

Comment: @BradleyThomas Yes, it is just displaying the string BS but it was meant to to the substring and length -1 not display it. It feels like it is bypassing the if and else if even if it has the same condition and im not sure why?

Comment: Are you sure its equal to exactly "BS"?  That there isn't any non visible control characters?  Lots of serial port protocols append control characters to strings.  Run a debugger, and make sure the string length isn't larger than 2.

Comment: @GabeSechan im pretty sure it is the same string I might be missing something the message is from a bluetooth data which arduino bluetooth print. When I do string variable length() it displays 1024...

Comment: @GabeSechan that's weird it gave me a bs��������������������������� in log.e. How would i remove this extra characters?

Comment: @GabeSechan i figured it out! i used replacedAll to remove the question marks! thank you so much!!